# ruby hash to javascript hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a ruby hash that i want to convert into a specific javascript hash.
Here is the ruby hash `keyval`

```
{    
   "Former Administration / Neutral"=>24,     
   "Media Personality / P"=>2,     
   "Journalist / Neutral"=>32,   
   "Consultant / Neutral"=>2,

   ...     

   "Journalist / P"=>11, 
   "Expert / Neutral"=>1, 
   "Activist / Neutral"=>15 
}
```

Into javascript hash

```
{data: "Former Administration / Neutral", frequency: (24) },
{data: "Media Personality / P", frequency: (2) },
{data: "Journalist / Neutral", frequency: (32) },
{data: "Consultant / Neutral", frequency: (2) },

 ...

{data: "Journalist / P", frequency: (11) },
{data: "Expert / Neutral", frequency: (1) },
{data: "Activist / Neutral", frequency: (15) }
```

Tried

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < <%= keyval.size %>; i++) {
obj["data"] = <%= keyval.keys[i] %>;
obj["frequency"] = '(' + <%= @keyval.values[i] %> + ')';
}
```

But the loop is not working `obj` return the first element of the ruby hash `frequency=24` and does not escape the space in `Former Administration`. Why?

Comment: This definitly can not work, as `i` is a JS variable, but you are trying to use it in the RoR code. And you are overwriting the same object in every cycle of the loop. You need a Ruby loop, not a JavaScript loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a to_json method for converting ruby hashes and arrays into json objects.  You could make an array of hashes using the first hash, then call to_json on it.  Then, you're doing all your data manipulation in ruby, and just converting the format to json at the end.

```
hash = {    
   "Former Administration / Neutral"=>24,     
   "Media Personality / P"=>2,     
   "Journalist / Neutral"=>32,   
   "Consultant / Neutral"=>2,
   "Journalist / P"=>11, 
   "Expert / Neutral"=>1, 
   "Activist / Neutral"=>15 
}   
arr = []
hash1.each do |k,v|
  arr << {:data => k, :frequency => v}
end
arr.to_json
```

gives

```
"[{"data":"Journalist / P","frequency":11},{"data":"Activist / Neutral","frequency":15},{"data":"Former Administration / Neutral","frequency":24},{"data":"Expert / Neutral","frequency":1},{"data":"Journalist / Neutral","frequency":32},{"data":"Consultant / Neutral","frequency":2},{"data":"Media Personality / P","frequency":2}]"
```

You said that you wanted a "javascript hash", but what it looks like you have in your question, at the end, is an array without the square brackets.  My result is a valid json object representation which is an array of objects.  Which i think is actually what you want.

Comment: How to get rid of the `"` and have `"[{data:"Journalist / P",frequency:11},{data:"Activist / Neutral",frequency:15},{data:"Former Administration / Neutral","frequency":24},{data:"Expert / Neutral",frequency:1},{data:"Journalist / Neutral",frequency:32},{data:"Consultant / Neutral",frequency:2},{data:"Media Personality / P",frequency:2}]"`

Comment: using `arr.to_json.html_safe` did the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can dothis using `map` and `join`

```
keyval.map{|k,v| "{data: \"#{k}\", frequency: (#{v}) }" }.join(",\r\n")
```

the map method provides the key as `k` and the value as `v` in this example.

Comment: have an error doesn't like the `"` .Error: `SyntaxError: syntax error
 

{&quot;Former Administration / Neutral&quot;=&gt;44, &quot;Me`

Comment: @mamesaye you need to add `.html_safe` at the end of the statement if you render it inside an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = [];
<% for i in 0..@keyval.size-1 { %>
  data.push({});
  data[<%= i %>]["data"] = <%= @keyval.keys[i] %>;
  data[<%= i %>]["frequency"] = '(' + <%= @keyval.values[i] %> + ')';
<% } %>
```

So you will get an array of those objects.

Comment: that was helpful, thanks. just change some stuff for it to work `var data = []; <% for i in 0..@keyval.size-1 %> data.push({}); data[<%= i %>]["data"] = "<%= @keyval.keys[i] %>"; data[<%= i %>]["frequency"] = '(' + <%= @keyval.values[i] %> + ')'; <% end %> console.log(data);` but is is adding `object` before each element... `[Object { data="Former Administration / Neutral", frequency="(24)"}, Object { data="Media Personality / P", frequency="(2)"}, ...]`  How to get rid of it?